# Let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ be a real positive definite hermitian form in Hilbert space $H$. Prove that if $\langle x,x\rangle =0$ then $x=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, bilinear-form

I think it may be connected to the Schwarz inequality.

Because if $\langle x, x \rangle = 0$ implies the Schwarz inequality, then $\langle x, y \rangle = 0$ too for $x \neq y$.

And for some reason, because $\langle x, y \rangle = 0$ for $x \neq y$ when $\langle x, x \rangle = 0$, this means that $x = 0$.

It's clear that $\langle x, x \rangle = 0$ for $x = 0$, but what we have to prove is that $\langle x , x \rangle = 0 \ \Rightarrow \ x = 0$. So theoretically, there might be other non-zero $x$ which will fulfill $\langle x, x \rangle = 0$.

Comment: I would think that $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$ should count as a hermitian form in $\mathbb{C}^2$.  But with this hermitian form, $\langle (1,1), (1,1) \rangle = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix} = 0$.  Unless I'm totally off with my interpretation of the question.

Comment: @DanielSchepler it's real hermitian actually, sorry for the confusion, I'll edit the question

Comment: I don't think my counterexample needs to change, except that now the matrix induces a hermitian form on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: What's your definition of Hermitian form?  Under the normal definition (as given at [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitianForm.html), for instance), it's simply not true, even for *non-negative real* Hermitian forms. Here's a counterexample
$$
\pmatrix{-1&1&-1}\pmatrix{1&1&0\\1&2&1\\0&1&1}\pmatrix{-1\\1\\-1}=0\ .
$$

Comment: It's true if and only if the Hermitian form is [positive definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_quadratic_form#Associated_symmetric_bilinear_form) or negative definite, in which case it's a trivial consequence of the definition of positive or negative definiteness

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Thanks for pointing it out! I absolutely forgot to include that this hermitian form is positive definite i.e. $\langle x, x \rangle \ge 0$. But why is it a trivial consequence?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz solves any and all problems in hilbertian analysis (half-joking but still).

Comment: The real hermitian form $x_1^2$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is positive definite and vanishes for $x$ with $x_1=0.$

Comment: @anon "Positive definite" means $\ \langle x,x\rangle\color{red}{>}0\ $ *unless* $\ x=0\ $, not merely that $\ \langle x,x\rangle\ge0\ $. There are Hermitian forms which satisfy this latter condition for *all* $\ x\ $ but for which there exist $\ x\ne0\ $ such that $\ \langle x,x\rangle=0\ $. I gave an example of one in my first comment. They are called "positive $\color{red}{semi}$definite", or "non-negative (semidefinite)", but *never* "positive definite", which always has the meaning I gave at the start of this comment.